# SwiftUI: how to make an enum allCases observable?

Tags: swiftui

I come from the UIKit universe and am struggling to understand SwiftUI's object observers.

Here is what I have:

**MyEnum**

```
enum MyEnum: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    static var all: [MyEnum] { MyEnum.allCases.sorted(by: { $0.value > $1.value }) }

    case value1 = "value1"
    case value2 = "value2"

    var value: Double { UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: rawValue) }
}
```

I also have a service that calls an API and updates all the `MyEnum` values (by setting the new value in the `UserDefaults`).

And the UI:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestHeader()
        TestList()
    }
}

struct TestHeader: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            APIService.reloadAll()
        }, label: {
            Text("Update")
        }
    }
}

struct TestList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(MyEnum.all) {
                MyEnumRow(myEnum: $0)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}

struct MyEnumRow: View {
    var myEnum: MyEnum 

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text(myEnum.rawValue)
            Text(myEnum.value)
        }
    }    
}
```

Of course when I tap the update button the myEnum list isn't updated, but I don't know how to make it responsive to content change. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@AppStorage` to watch a particular value in `UserDefaults`. This is slightly more complex in your case because you don't know what key to be watching until the view is created. I opted to have the `AppStorage` passed in from the parent view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestHeader()
        TestList()
    }
}

struct TestHeader: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Double(Date().timeIntervalSince1970), forKey: MyEnum.allCases.first!.rawValue)
        }) {
            Text("Update")
        }
    }
}

struct TestList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(MyEnum.all) {
                MyEnumRow(myEnum: $0, valueStorage: AppStorage(wrappedValue: 0, $0.rawValue))
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}

struct MyEnumRow: View {
    var myEnum: MyEnum
    @AppStorage var valueStorage : Double
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text(myEnum.rawValue)
            Text("\(valueStorage)")
        }
    }
}

enum MyEnum: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    static var all: [MyEnum] { MyEnum.allCases.sorted(by: { $0.value > $1.value }) }

    case value1 = "value1"
    case value2 = "value2"

    var value: Double { UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: rawValue) }
    
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}
```